# Init routes for react router based on ajax response

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

In my app I have privelege for Admin page and after login I want to grant access to this page only for users who have this privelege.

Is any way to load routes for  component with ajax before application is inited?
Is any way to change routes for  component after some actions (like login)?
What is the best practice for solving this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js) in the `react-router` repo. They use the `onEnter` property to check for authorization:

```
<Router history={withExampleBasename(browserHistory, __dirname)}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="login" component={Login} />
    <Route path="logout" component={Logout} />
    <Route path="about" component={About} />
    <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={requireAuth} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

The [onEnter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) prop is a function that is called before entering the route:

```
function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
    replace({
      pathname: '/login',
      state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
    })
  }
}
```

The onEnter function has the following call signature:

```
onEnter(nextState, replace, callback?)
```

This gives you access to the state to check if the user has admin privileges.

The other often discussed approach is using higher order components. The components that require admin rights do not need to know about that but are wrapped with by a component that restricts access.

Some more information:

https://blog.tighten.co/react-101-routing-and-auth
https://github.com/joshgeller/react-redux-jwt-auth-example
https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/

As always the client isn't to be trusted and the data should be secured on the server.